# Complex potential question

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential-theory

Consider the ﬂow described by the complex potential
$$w = Be^{−imπ}z^{m+1}$$
where $B > 0$ and $m ∈ (0,1]$.

(i) Determine the stream function $ψ$ and the potential $φ$ in plane polar coordinates $(r,θ)$.

(ii) Determine $u_r$ and $u_θ$ in plane polar coordinates $(r,θ)$.

For (i), I got $ψ=Br^{m+1} \sin ((m+1) \theta - m \pi)$ and $φ=Br^{m+1} \cos ((m+1) \theta - m \pi)$, (is this correct?)

What exactly is $u$??????

Comment: $u_r$ and $u_\theta$ are the radial and angular velocity components.

Comment: @David but what exactly is $u$ on its own? Is it $\partial  φ / \partial x$?

Comment: The velocity potential and streamfunction should be defined in terms of the velocity. You have no $x$ variable here, so you definitely can't do $\partial\varphi/\partial x$. $u$ is the velocity. $u_r=\partial\varphi/\partial r$ and $u_\theta=\partial\varphi/\partial\theta$, but this is really the definition of the velocity potential.